# Rotate entry every hour

Tags: channel-entries, php

I would like to rotate between two entries each hour depending on the time of the day.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the expressionengine current time variable in a conditional

```
{if {current_time format="%G"} < 12}
   {exp:channel:entries url_title="morning"}
      ...
   {/exp:channel:entries}
{if:else}
   {exp:channel:entries url_title="evening"}
      ...
   {/exp:channel:entries}
{/if}
```

Comment: If you don't wish to have 2 channel entries, you can pass the url_title through embeds